# The tea bag problem: probability of extracting a single bag of tea

Tags: probability

Suppose you have a bunch of tea bags in a box, initially in pairs, like these:

[image]

Let us suppose the box initially contains only joined pairs of tea bags, say $N_0$ of them (thus making for a total of $2N_0$ tea bags).

Every time you want to make yourself a tea, you put a hand in the box and randomly extract a tea bag.
Sometimes you will find yourself with a joined pair, in which case you split it, take one for your tea, and put the other back into the box.
If you instead extract a single tea bag (which was already split before), you just take it.

Now if you ever happened to be in a similar situation, you will probably have noticed that after a while you will almost always extract single tea bags and seldolmly find doubles (which is not surprising of course).
The question is, **what exactly is the probability $p_k$ of extracting a single tea bag, after $k$ tea bags have already been picked?**

Suppose for this problem that each time there is an equal probability of extracting *any* of the tea bags, regardless of them being joined with another or not, so that after the first step (in which we necessarily extract and split a double) the probability of extracting a single bag is $p_1=\frac{1}{2N_0-1}$.

It is relatively easy, just by computing the values of $p_k$ for the first $k$s, to see that the answer to the problem is quite nice:
$$p_k = \frac{k}{2N_0 -1}.$$
How can we prove this?

---

An interesting variation of the problem is asking what happens if we instead consider the picking of a pair as a single event (instead that as two, as in the above considered case).
With this assumption the previous formula does not hold, as computing the first values of $p_k$ shows:
$$ p_1 = \frac{1}{N_0}, \\ p_2 = \frac{2(N_0-1)}{N_0^2} .$$

Comment: Beautifully presented, both visually as well as textually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is a condensed version of @lulu 's answer.)

If in drawing${}_{k+1}\>$ I pick a certain bag $b$ then any other  bag, in particular the partner of $b$,  is among the $k$ previously drawn bags with probability
$${k\over 2N-1}\ .$$

Comment: Well it's hardly getting simpler than that! Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 5):

Say you select tea bag $i$.  Your question, then, is what is the probability that teabag $\hat i$ has previously been selected. (where $\forall i$, teabag $i$ was initially paired with $\hat i$).  thus we are asked to compute the probability that a given teabag survived the selection process conditioned on the fact that we know some other specified teabag did survive.  the conditioning just requires us to start with a sample of $2N_0-1$ and then the probability that a given teabag survived $k$ selections is $$\frac {2N_0-2}{2N_0-1}\times \frac {2N_0-3}{2N_0-2}\times \cdots\times \frac {2N_0-(k+1)}{2N_0-k}=\frac {2N_0-(k+1)}{2N_0-1}$$

The answer you seek is the compliment of this, hence $$1-\frac {2N_0-(k+1)}{2N_0-1}=\frac k{2N_0-1}$$

Comment: Your solution is very elegant, but I don't get the derivation. The desired probability is that of drawing a single tea bag, *any* single tea bag. You, on the other hand, seem to be calculating the probability of drawing a specific tea bag. Then shouldn't the final probability be multiplied by $2N_0$?

Comment: The answer doesn't depend on what $i$ is, I just introduced it for specificity.  Whichever bag you pick, your only question concerns the survival of its mate.

Comment: By way of analogy:  suppose I ask "what's the probability of drawing a pair if I select two cards from a deck?"  To do that, I select the first (don't care what it is) and then remark that $\frac 3{51}$ choices for the second give me a pair.  This works because the answer is independent of which I select first.  it would be different if, say, I include the two jokers.  Now I have to worry that I chose a joker first.  That's because I broke the symmetry...jokers are different from the others.  Similarly, in your question, the key point is that every tea bag is the same.

Comment: Put in other way: $P(S_k) = \sum_i P(S_k \wedge t_k=i) = \sum_i P(S_k \mid t_k=i) P(t_k=i) =   P(S_k \mid t_k=i) $ where the last equality results because  $P(t_k=i)$ is a constant. Here $S_k$ is the event of interest (single bag in extraction $k$) and $t_k$ is the label of the bag.  What is computed in lulu's answer. is $P(S_k \mid t_k=i)$

Answer (score 1):

lulu wrote an excellent answer. Nevertheless I would like to offer a small variation on lulu's derivation that I find easier to understand.

For every tea-bag $s$
$$
\substack{\text{Probability}\\\text{of drawing $s$}\\\text{on the $k+1$th draw}\\\text{while its pair, $t$}\\\text{is still attached}} = \underset{\substack{\text{avoid $s,t$}\\\text{on 1st draw}}}{\underbrace{\frac{2N-2}{2N}}}\underset{\substack{\text{avoid $s,t$}\\\text{on 2nd draw}}}{\underbrace{\frac{2N-3}{2N-1}}}\cdots\underset{\substack{\text{avoid $s,t$}\\\text{on $k$-th draw}}}{\underbrace{\frac{2N-(k+1)}{2N-(k-1)}}}\underset{\substack{\text{draw $s$}\\\text{on $k+1$-th draw}}}{\underbrace{\frac{1}{2N-k}}}
$$

Repeat for every tea bag and add up to obtain
$$
\begin{align}
\substack{\text{Probability}\\\text{of drawing a tea bag}\\\text{on the $k+1$th draw}\\\text{while its pair}\\\text{is still attached}} &= 2N\ \frac{2N-2}{2N}\frac{2N-3}{2N-1}\cdots\frac{2N-(k+1)}{2N-(k-1)}\frac{1}{2N-k} \\
&= \frac{2N-2}{2N-1}\frac{2N-3}{2N-2}\cdots\frac{2N-(k+1)}{2N-k} \\
&= \frac{2N-(k+1)}{2N-1} 
\end{align}
$$

Now take the complement to obtain
$$
p_k = 1-\frac{2N-(k+1)}{2N-1} = \frac{k}{2N-1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way to deal with this. I get Barry's Tea, which does come in paired bags. Furthermore, each bag is $3$ grams of tea, where the vast majority of teabags one sees are $2$ grams each. I get the Gold Blend and the Irish Breakfast.

I take both teabags and put them in the mug and then pour boiling water on them. And wait five minutes. More flavor. Oh, I do separate the two teabags, because I later pull them out with tweezers and squeeze them with teabag tongs to get most of the liquid out. That would be clumsy with joined bags.

http://www.barrystea.ie/

http://www.englishteastore.com/tea-bag-squeezer.html

Afterthought: Barry's is the first tea that I have regularly purchased that comes with no string. It is entirely possible that teabags with strings are typically two grams and teabags without them are typically three grams. Oh, and I sometimes get a very nice pu-erh, loose leaves, from a nearby shop called Far Leaves.

http://www.farleaves.com/

http://www.farleaves.com/collections/puer-teas

Comment: There's yet another tea bag trick that I know, but it demands a degree of flexibility and is not altogether appropriate for this forum.

Comment: @EvanAad well, yes. I first heard of that in a movie, http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0126604/     This is also why Bill Maher refers to the Tea Party as the Teabaggers.

Comment: mmmh... probably I'm missing something but.. what?

Comment: @glS My answer has nothing to do with mathematics. I was just charmed by the topic, a very familiar one. Usually my answers of this sort are deleted within a day, but perhaps nobody has thought to flag this one. For the second part, look up teabagging online, it really is not appropriate to give any detail here; since I just looked it up, apparently I was not entirely correct in what I thought was meant by the term.